# LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'OLDNAMES.lib'

Tags: python, windows, pip, installation

I am trying to install [glumpy](https://glumpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) by running `pip install glumpy`. It downloads the wheel for glumpy (and [triangle](https://rufat.be/triangle/)) and then, while building the wheel, spits out

```
  E:\-----\Development\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DVOID=void -DREAL=double -DNO_TIMER=1 -DTRILIBRARY=1 -DANSI_DECLARATORS=1 -Ic -IE:\*****\Anaconda3\envs\quad\include -IE:\*****\Anaconda3\envs\quad\include -IE:\-----\Development\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include -IE:\-----\Development\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17134.0\cppwinrt" /Tctriangle/core.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\triangle/core.obj
    core.c
  E:\-----\Development\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO /LIBPATH:E:\*****\Anaconda3\envs\quad\libs /LIBPATH:E:\*****\Anaconda3\envs\quad\PCbuild\amd64 /LIBPATH:E:\-----\Development\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\lib\x64 /LIBPATH:E:\-----\Development\VisualStudio\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\lib\x64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\lib\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.17134.0\um\x64" /EXPORT:PyInit_core build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\c/triangle.obj build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\triangle/core.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\triangle\core.cp38-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\c\core.cp38-win_amd64.lib
  LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'OLDNAMES.lib'
  error: command 'E:\\-----\\Development\\VisualStudio\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\link.exe' failed with exit status 1104
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for glumpy
```

I googled around and saw an old solution

> Solution 1:
>
> - Include following directory in LIB Environment Variable:
>
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\lib

But I don't have a LIB env variable and the directory and similar directories do not exist.

Please help, I've been trying to install this package for nonths!

Update: I got my hands on some wheels for triangle, which I could install. If there are wheels of glumpy for win_amd64, please point me to them!

Answer (score 0):

Neither `glumpy` nor `triangle` provide binary wheels, they only provide source code. To compile them you need to install a lot of C/C++/Python dependencies.

For triangle you need https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~quake/triangle.html.

For glumpy: https://github.com/glumpy/glumpy#dependencies

*Upd*. I see triangle's `makefile` requires Unix programs (`/bin/rm`) and X Windows libraries. This seem to be Unix-only package. Not for Windows.

Comment: Do I need to compile triangle.c after download and extraction? Where do I put it? Shouldn't it be included in the pypi triangle package? Sorry for those questions, but so far, you have been the most helpful, thank you!

Comment: No idea, sorry, I'm seeing these packages for the 1st time :-) In `triangle.zip` I see a `makefile` so 1st thing to try is to download the archive, unzip it into a separate directory and run `make` in the directory.

Comment: I see `makefile` requires Unix programs and X Windows libraries. This seem to be Unix-only package. Not for Windows.

Comment: I think it looks like the file showme.c can't be compiled on Windows, only with X-libraries, but it doesn't say so about the original library. I do hope so at least!

Comment: Also, I have cloned the triangle (python) git repo and tried to install it via setup.py, but it raises the same error, although the installation instructions specify that that should suffice and there are `*.c` files in the repo.

Comment: I installed triangle with `pip install triangle` on Linux for Python 2.7 and 3.7.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212426/discussion-between-justaguy-and-phd).